# Why are my theorems not numbered by letters?

Tags: numbering, theorems, counters, code

I'm trying to enumerate the main theorems from my paper using letters instead of numbers. I've tried using the following code but it's not working (at least the counter is!)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{theoremno}{Theorem}

\newcounter{teoremas} 
\setcounter{teoremas}{0} 
\newtheorem{teorema}[teoremas]{Theorem} 
\renewcommand{\theteorema}{\Alph{teoremas}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{teorema} Teorema a
\end{teorema}

\begin{teorema} Teorema B
\end{teorema}

\end{document}
```

The output is just

[image]

What is wrong with my code? Can it be saved or should I start it over from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a special environment for your main theorems.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{maintheorem}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\themaintheorem}{\Alph{maintheorem}}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{theorem}
This is a standard theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
This is a standard theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{maintheorem}
This is one of the main theorems.
\end{maintheorem}

\section{Another}

\begin{theorem}
This is a standard theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{maintheorem}
This is one of the main theorems.
\end{maintheorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: “Define a special environment for your main theorems”? Wasn’t this also what the OP did? Why does this work better?

Comment: This worked, thanks! I'm pretty sure I've tried something pretty close to this but I might have messed things up.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\Alph{theorem}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
  Hello
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Problem is, this will enumerate ALL my theorems with letters; I want only my main results, and to be able to call other things theorems; these will be numbered as usual.

Comment: You can define another theorem env like `\newtheorem{maintheorem}{Theorem}` and redefine the `\themaintheorem`.@Marra